# AngularJS 1.5 inject service into directive in ES6

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6

I'm currently playing with AngularJS 1.5 and ES6 build with Webpack.

I have created a directive "UniqueValidator" to check if an email is not yet used. To do that, of course I have make a service called "RegisterService".

I'm trying to inject this service inside the directive but it doesn't work... (RegisterService is undefined)
I'm pretty sure it's a little glitch but I can see it...

My module definition:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import 'angular-ui-router';
import 'angular-messages';

import {UniqueValidator} from './register.directive';
import registerComponent from './register.component';
import {RegisterService} from './../services';


const module = angular.module('register.module', ['ui.router', 'ngMessages'])
  .component('register', registerComponent)
  .config(($stateProvider) => {
    "ngInject";     // ng-annotate doesn't handle arrow functions automatically; need to add the directive prologue.
    $stateProvider
      .state('register', {
        url: '/register',
        template: '<register></register>'
      });
  })
  .service('registerService', RegisterService)
  .directive('uniqueValidator', () => new UniqueValidator)
  .name;

export default module;
```

My directive:

```
class UniqueValidator {
  /*@ngInject*/
  constructor(registerService) {
    this.restrict = 'A';
    this.require = 'ngModel';
    this.registerService = registerService;
    console.log("Register service", this.registerService);
  }

  link(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      if (!ngModel || ngModel.$error[attrs.name]) return;

      ngModel.$asyncValidators.unique = function() {
        console.log('RegisterService', this.registerService);
        return this.registerService.isUnique('email', element.val());
      };
  }
}

export {UniqueValidator};
```

The annotation /*@ngInject*/ works well for my controllers for example.. so why not with my directive?

Answer (score 2):

You should annotate constructor function instead of a class:

```
class UniqueValidator {
  constructor(registerService) {
    /*@ngInject*/
    this.restrict = 'A';
    this.require = 'ngModel';
    this.registerService = registerService;
    console.log("Register service", this.registerService);
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but for anyone having problems. The only way I could get this working was to inject onto a controller function instead.  And set services to scope as `this` was never available.

```
class UniqueValidator {
   controller( $scope, registerService ){
     /*ngInject*/
     $scope.registerService = registerService;
   }

   link( scope, element, attrs, ngModel ){
     console.log(scope.registerService);
   }
}
```

Our injections are sadly done manually with:

```
UniqueValidator.$inject = ['$scope', 'registerService'];
```

But I can't imagine it will be any difference with `ngInject`