# How to inject service into directive in AngularJS with ES6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, components, directive

Here are my directives index:

```
'use strict';

import SignupService from './core/services/signup.service';

import FooterDirective from './components/footer/footer.directive';
import MenuDirective from './components/menu/menu.directive';

export default angular.module('index.components', [])
    .directive('footer', FooterDirective)
    .directive('menu', [MenuDirective, function(SignupService) {}]);
```

and directive:

```
import tmpl from './menu.tpl.html';

class Menu {
    constructor($scope) {
        this.scope = $scope;
        this.restrict = 'AC';
        this.transclude = true;
        this.replace = true;
        this.templateUrl = tmpl;
        this.scope = {
            ngSrc: "@",
        };
    }

    link(scope, elem, attrs) {

        console.log(scope.SignupService);

        scope.logoutCall = () => {
            this.SignupService.logoutSubmit();
        }
    }
}
function factory() {
    "ngInject";

    return new Menu(...arguments);
}

export default factory;
```

I need to get access to `Signup Service` from Menu directive, but i have this error - `Incorrect injection token! Expected service name as string, got function factory()`. How and what is the best practice to inject service to directive. Thx for gelp.

Answer (score 0):

Your dependency injection seems to be wrong.

Instead of

```
.directive('menu', [MenuDirective, function(SignupService) {}]);
```

there should be

```
.directive('menu', ['SignupService', function(SignupService) {}]);
```

Comment: and where is declaration for Menu directive?

Comment: Look at this then. It seems to be similar to your problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40333189/angularjs-1-5-inject-service-into-directive-in-es6